# Send js data-id and receive php?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm currently working on how to send a JavaScript to PHP server side.
I tryed playing with jquery ajax, but it requires a submit (as far as i understand?) before it can send data. My question is how can i send som data from Javascript to PHP without submitting?

I fiddled with folowing code, but can't receive the data at editproduct.php

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/editproduct/editproduct.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    id1: '1',
    id2: '2'
});

//PHP:
print_r($_GET); //Does not show any content
```

Comment: How are you actually checking what the PHP script returns? Try adding `success: function(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: Well actualle it's alerting all the content wich is that is on the editproduct page, including html, all stuff, not the real data like id1,id2...

Comment: So how do you know it's not receiving your GET data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `type: 'GET'` the data will be stored in `$_GET`. If you want to store your data in `$_POST`, use `type: 'POST'`.

Also, the apostrophes around your vars' values are not needed. Try

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/editproduct/editproduct.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    id1: 1,
    id2: 2
  }
});
```

**(and mind the missing curly bracket which suppose to close the data section)**

Comment: see my edit above. Also, which error do you get on your console? (use firebug)

Comment: Hmm... I tried your suggestion, but it still does not work. A strangs thing is though that the data is containing all the data from editprocut.php not id1,id2 as specified. No errors in console :/ I also tried using post in both files...

Comment: See the additional edit about the curly braket. By your comment it sounds that SOME data is stored in $_GET. What does print_r($_GET) echoes?

Comment: I have seen your edits and noticed them by my self :P
$_GET echoes array() (empty array)

Comment: even the MISSING CURLY BRAKET? (and how do you know it's a spelling issue, what error do you relate to?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24130/discussion-between-simon-duun-and-roy)

Answer (score 2):

`print_r($_GET);` might get you there.